# Why is the accuracy on the test dataset very low when training a neural network on an IMU dataset?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, convolution, rnn

I am trying to train an IMU (Inertial Measurement Unit) dataset. The dataset contain 6 features (3-gyro, 3-accelerometer) and 1 label column. I have build a neural network via Conv1D, LSTM and Dense layers respectively (in Keras Framework). The train set accuracy achieve %89 accuracy but validation accuracy is stucked on %27. I know it means overfitting. I tried to use dropout layers and hyperparamter tunning but validation accuracy is still low. The model can't predict good solutions if I test on untrained data(test set). What can I do to increase accuracy?

You can check my notebook and dataset [here](https://www.kaggle.com/dasmehdixtr/best-solution-via-conv-lstm-dense-85-acc).

Will the accuracy on the test dataset increase if we add noise on the tabular data?

Or, do I need to have more data to make a generalization and have good test accuracy?

Comment: The notebook you've linked show a validation accuracy of 86% so you might have linked the wrong notebook.

Comment: In that notebook, I used training set as validation set. That's why validation accuracy looks well. When I split data into test-train set, the test accuracy stucked on %20.